# kotlin SQLite database always writing default values, never new ones

Tags: kotlin, sqlite, android-sqlite

here is the class I set up for my database. database handler being the inner class.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.util.Log
import java.sql.Date

class Scores {
    var id : Int = 0
    var dataBaseName = "ScoreDatabase"
    var averageTime = 0.0f
    val date = Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString()


    constructor(averageTime:Float) {
        this.averageTime = averageTime
        Log.d("Poop", averageTime.toString())
    }
    constructor()

    inner class DataBaseHandler(var context:Context, tableName:String): SQLiteOpenHelper(context, dataBaseName, null,1){

        val TABLE_NAME = tableName
        val COL_ID = "id"
        val COL_AVG = "Average_Time"
        val COL_DATE = "Date"

        override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
            val createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +" (" +
                    COL_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    COL_AVG + " VARCHAR(256)," +
                    COL_DATE +" VARCHAR(256)"

            db?.execSQL(createTable)
        }

        override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        fun insertData(score: Scores){
            val db = this.writableDatabase
            var cv = ContentValues()
            cv.put(COL_AVG,score.averageTime)
            cv.put(COL_DATE,score.date)
            var result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv)
            if(result == -1.toLong())
                Log.d("POOP", "fail score table in addition")
            else
                Log.d("POOP", "Success score table in addition" )
        }

        fun readData(): MutableList<Scores>{
            var list: MutableList<Scores> = ArrayList()

            val db = this.readableDatabase
            val query = "Select * from $TABLE_NAME"
            val result = db.rawQuery(query,null)

            if (result.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    var score = Scores()
                    var id = result.getString(0).toInt()
                    var AvgTime = result.getString(1).toFloat()
                    var date = result.getString(2).toString()
                    list.add(score)
                }while (result.moveToNext())
            }
            result.close()
            db.close()
            return list
        }

    }

}
```

I tried this where the scores class and the handler were two separate classes, but it generated the same results.

here is how I write to the database (from 4 separate activities. in each activity the tablename is different. in this one for example it is 'additionDataBase')

```
val scores = Scores("%.3f".format(timeKeeper.averageNumber).toFloat())
val db = scores.DataBaseHandler(context, "additionDataBase")
db.insertData(scores)
```

and here is how I read from the database which is in a different activity that shows the `averageTime` from each table. here is the code for one of them

```
val context: Context? = activity

val adb = Scores().DataBaseHandler(context!!,"additionDataBase")
val data = adb.readData()
TextViewAdScore.text = data[0].averageTime.toString() + "    " + data[1].date
```

I think I am missing something, but I can't seem to find what it is.

so far, no matter how many times I do this. the output is always 0.0f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what you do in `readData`:

```
var score = Scores()
var id = result.getString(0).toInt()
var AvgTime = result.getString(1).toFloat()
var date = result.getString(2).toString()
list.add(score)
```

`id`, `AvgTime`, and `date` are retrieved but not used in any way, so your code is equivalent to just writing `list.add(Scores())`. (Side note: there's no reason for them to be `var`, and why the case inconsistency between `AvgTime` and the rest?)

Comment: Oh. I see where I went wrong now. Ahhh it makes so much sense. Thank you! Case looks inconsistent, but it's too separate column names vs variables and other similar things. I should really do that better.

Comment: If this solves the problem, you may want to accept the answer.